# Javascript Associative Array cant post via php

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Iam trying to post an Javascript Object via php, but i cant get the value in PHP, iam using laravel framework.

my array,

```
[type: "sadf", level: "sadfasdf"]
```

javascript code,

```
var data_push = Array();
$('form').on('change', 'select, textarea, input', function(t,s){            
            var key    = $(this).attr('id');
            var value  = $(this).val();     
            data_push[key] = value;
        });
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $.post("{!! URL::to('test') !!}", {
                            _token      : tempcsrf,                     
                            req_data    : data_push
                        },
                        function (resp, textStatus, jqXHR) {                        
                            alert(resp);
                        });
});
```

php code,

```
public function workbook_save(Request $request_data)
    {       
        $require_data   = $request_data->req_data;  
        print_r($require_data);
    }
```

Tried also `JSON.stringfy(data_push) ,json_decode` but no luck, i cant get the Javascript object in php, donno what iam doing wrong here, pls advice.

Comment: As far as I am aware, javascript has no such concept of an associative array, you can however use an object in place of said array... `{type: "sadf", level:"asdasdasd"}`

Answer (score 0):

This is what your JS does:

1. Creates an array
2. Sets up an event handler to populate the array when things change in the form
3. Posts the (empty) array to the server

Later on, things will change in the form and data will be put in the array.

The server knows nothing about this because you already sent its contents.

You need to change your logic so you only make the POST request when you are ready to send the data.

Comment: thanks for your response, can you suggest any logic ?

Comment: I don't know when you want to send the data.

Comment: in an button click only

Comment: Then put the code to send the data in a click handler.